# How to iterate through a dictionay and a list to create a new dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

From a Project, I am getting a list of dictionaries that look like this:

> METTS MARK = {'salary': 365788, 'to_messages': 807, 'deferral_payments': 'NaN', 'total_payments': 1061827, 'exercised_stock_options': 'NaN', 'bonus': 600000, 'restricted_stock': 585062, 'shared_receipt_with_poi': 702, 'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN', 'total_stock_value': 585062, 'expenses': 94299, 'loan_advances': 'NaN', 'from_messages': 29, 'other': 1740, 'from_this_person_to_poi': 1, 'poi': False, 'director_fees': 'NaN', 'deferred_income': 'NaN', 'long_term_incentive': 'NaN', 'email_address': 'mark.metts@enron.com', 'from_poi_to_this_person': 38}

What I want to do is to take each of the values, feature scale it, replace the 'NaN' value with 0, then return it back into its rightful place in the dictionary.

The code that I tried looks like this:

Load the dictionary containing the dataset

```
with open("final_project_dataset.pkl", "r") as data_file:
    data_dict = pickle.load(data_file)
```

A key in the dataset called total was creating a clear outlier, so I removed it

```
del data_dict["TOTAL"]
```

Intuitively picking my features

```
my_features = [
    'poi',
    'salary',#
    'bonus',#
    'exercised_stock_options',#
    'total_stock_value',#
    'total_payments',
    'expenses',
    'loan_advances',#
    'deferral_payments',
    'deferred_income',
    'restricted_stock',#
    'restricted_stock_deferred',
    'long_term_incentive',#
    'shared_receipt_with_poi',#
    #'from_this_person_to_poi',
    #director_fees',
    #'from_messages',
    #'to_messages',
    #'from_poi_to_this_person'
]


keys = data_dict.keys()
values = data_dict.values()
```

replacing NaN values with 0 values

```
list_of_values = []
for key in keys:
        tmp_list = []
        for feature in my_features:
            try:
                data_dict[key][feature]
            except KeyError:
                print "error: key ", feature, " not present"
            value = data_dict[key][feature]
            if value=="NaN":
                value = 0
            tmp_list.append( float(value) )
        list_of_values.append(tmp_list)
```

feature scaling with a min/max scaler

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
data_array = np.array(list_of_values)
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
rescaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data_array)
```

So, now I have a list of lists that looks like this:

> [0.         0.32916568 0.075      0.         0.01279963 0.01025327
>    0.41221264 0.         0.01569801 1.         0.18366453 0.10365427
>    0.         0.12715088]

I want to get these re-scaled values into the dictionary with the corresponding features... This is the code I wrote:

```
my_data_dict = []
for key in keys:
    key = {}
    for x in range( len(rescaled_data) ):
        for count in range( len(my_features) ):
            key[ my_features[count] ] = rescaled_data[x][count]        
    my_data_dict.append(key)
```

But I get a long list of dictionaries with the same values..for example:

> {'salary': 0.24744478779905296, 'deferral_payments': 0.01569801010492397, 'total_payments': 0.01228550157492107, 'loan_advances': 0.0, 'bonus': 0.075, 'restricted_stock_deferred': 0.1036542684938879, 'total_stock_value': 0.016735894091266437, 'expenses': 0.550692201098954, 'exercised_stock_options': 0.011200759837784508, 'poi': 1.0, 'deferred_income': 1.0, 'shared_receipt_with_poi': 0.1583046549538127, 'restricted_stock': 0.17265209213492153, 'long_term_incentive': 0.01380311165200059}
>
> {'salary': 0.24744478779905296, 'deferral_payments': 0.01569801010492397, 'total_payments': 0.01228550157492107, 'loan_advances': 0.0, 'bonus': 0.075, 'restricted_stock_deferred': 0.1036542684938879, 'total_stock_value': 0.016735894091266437, 'expenses': 0.550692201098954, 'exercised_stock_options': 0.011200759837784508, 'poi': 1.0, 'deferred_income': 1.0, 'shared_receipt_with_poi': 0.1583046549538127, 'restricted_stock': 0.17265209213492153, 'long_term_incentive': 0.01380311165200059}

How do I take the keys from data_dict (old dictionary) rescale it's data, and put it together in a new dictionary?

Comment: Have you considered putting your data into a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Joe Patten said, pandas make things easier, you can convert your dictionary into a dataframe, do your stuff then convert it back into a dictionary if you want:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

ser = pd.Series(METTS_MARK) #I am using your METTS_MARK

ser.replace('NaN',0,inplace=True)
ser.drop(index="email_address",inplace=True) #to make everything numerical so we can scale, you can add it back later

df = pd.DataFrame(ser)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df[0] = scaler.fit_transform(df)
```

after you're done:

```
newDict = df[0].to_dict()
```